# NodeJS crone best practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I have an APP where after I use **[cron][1]**.
I start my cron job something like:

```
this.timer = new CronJob('25 * * * * *', callback, null, true, null);
```

After I'm doing this I want to overwrite the this.timer with a new **CronJob** but diferent duration:

```
this.timer = new CronJob('50 * * * * *', callback, null, true, null);
```

Is this safe?

Does anyone knows and can explain a best practice of stopping current CronJob and start new one?

**Update**

Its better to use setTimeout() and clearTimeout()?

Comment: And what middleware are you using to create cronjobs from Node ?

Comment: Anyway, I'd say probably *no*, just overwriting the variable most likely doesn't stop the previous cron job, so now you have two of them running.

Comment: I'm using this.timer.stop() before overwriting, its stoping, but its safe?

Comment: If the cron job is stopped, it should be safe to overwrite the variable